# Design pattern for creating multiple objects of the same type

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am writing a search parser.There is an input search query(String) that needs to be converted to individual condition object.

For example, /perons/?q=age>50&name:mike

This query would translate into two condition objects.
1.GreaterThanCondition(String field, int value)
2.LikeCondition(String field, String value)

I have 14 such condition objects that implement the Condition Interface.

At runtime, I parse the string condition out of query (like "age>50") and I need to design an algorithm that would efficiently convert this condition into appropriate object (like GreaterThanCondition) efficiently.

Here is one algo I am thinking : Create a ConditionFactory. This ConditionFactory will take this string("age>50") and iterate over the existing 14 factories in a particular order (One factory for each condition) to match if the regex defined in the factory(For example, regex for GreaterThanConditionFactory can be [a-zA-Z0-9]+>+[0-9]+ . Based on regex match, GreaterThanConditionFactory can identify field(age) and value(50) from the condition and create GreaterThanConditionObject.

With this approach, I need to create 15 factories and 14 condition object.
I am not sure if creating that many factories is a good solution. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Why do you need 1 factory for each condition? Also, it sounds like you've created a Chain of Responsibility Factory... which doesn't sound like a *terrible* idea.

Comment: @Elliott If i put everything in my single factory, there will be too much logic and too many if else conditions in my ConditionFactory.For example, the code would look like : if("age>50").matches(GreaterThanConditionRegex) { find field and value; create GreaterThanConditon object; } else { .. }

Comment: Instead of a single factory, consider a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Definition). Your logic is going to have to go somewhere.

Comment: So for each regex, you want to trigger an algorithm which returns a condition? Couldn't you use some kind of mapping system, mapping each regex to an object which contains a method that processes the full string and returns a condition?

Comment: It is obvious that one pattern is not going to be enough to solve your problems. I believe [Interpreter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) may also help you at some point.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh I disagree that that would be too much logic for a single factory. You would have a single class that can parse expressions into objects. I would probably use a map from regex to factory method to keep the implementation clean, but that's all syntax, not semantics.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh There is nothing wrong with having if-else's in ConditionFactory to identify which concrete implementation. The whole idea behind a factory is to have the creation of all the objects in one place so maintenance becomes easy. Therefore, one factory should be enough. Also, instead of finding the field and value in the factory, why don't you pass it as arguments to the GreaterThanConditon constructor and have GreaterThanConditon class take care of parsing the string into field and value? Let the factory focus on creating objects and let the concrete implementations focus on parsing

Comment: @Elliott I can use Builder for each of the condition but that doesn't change a lot from the original solution.

Comment: @ Vince I cannot use regex as a key for map. Since the input can be (a>b&(c>d)) . I cannot convert a string into one specific regex.I have to do reverse; look for each regex and see if my input string matches that regex. But i  like the idea of creating another object for each condition which will take string and return condition (I called it factory for each condition)

Comment: @Mehmet I will look into Interpreter Pattern since it is mostly related to search/parser related problem.

Comment: @Vincent I just thought having a single factory will make it difficult for future developers to maintain it. If they have to add a new condition, implementing couple of classes/methods with logic will be easier than understanding the huge code of if else and finding where to insert their own logic.

Comment: @bot I originally thought of having constructor with String and constructor populating the fields. However, I thought from object prespective, it would be more clean and extensible if object can only be created out of the fields that define the object rather than syntax. In future, if i think my greater than sign is changed from > to >>, my object should not change.

Comment: There are other ways to tackle this change of sign. For instance, define a constant public static final String GREATER_THAN = ">" and use it everywhere in your code. If tomorrow you change > to >>, you just need to change the constant. You shouldn't be doing anything in the factory other than creating objects IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a really simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) that utilizes [CharacterIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/CharacterIterator.html), and a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example). This would be more readable, it would be faster than checking against 14 regexes, and it would support multiple query conditions.

```
public class QueryParser {
  CharacterIterator iterator;
  QueryBuilder queryBuilder;
  QueryConditionBuilder queryConditionBuilder;

  public Query parse(String text) {
    iterator = new StringCharacterIterator(text);
    queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
    while (hasNext()) {
      queryConditionBuilder = new QueryConditionBuilder();
      conditionSeparator();
      queryCondition();
      queryBuilder.withCondition(queryConditionBuilder.getQueryCondition()); 
    }
    return queryBuilder.getQuery();
  }

  public void conditionSeparator() {
     // if the next character is an &, then advance the iterator
  }

  public void parseQueryCondition() {
    key();
    operator();
    value();
  }

  public void parseKey() {
    // ... keep reading until the next character is not alphabetic
    queryConditionBuilder.withKey(key);
  }

  public void parseOperator() {
    // ... could be as simple as a one character check
    queryConditionBuilder.withOperator(operator);
  }

  public void parseValue() {
    // ... probably a number, so just read until the next character is not a digit or you reach the end of a string
    queryConditionBuilder.withValue(value);
  }

  public Character peek() {
     // delegate to character iterator
  }

  public Character next() {
     // delegate to character iterator
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
     // delegate to character iterator
  }
}
```